# What word best means "the state of being an expert"?

Tags: word-choice

In a tongue-in-cheek communique', I wish to say something to the effect of:

"But in the absence of such an actual expert, I have learned that the above is a losing battle.  I am being dragged, kicking and screaming, into widget expertcy."

But I don't think 'expertcy' is truly cromulent.  'Expertdom', maybe?

Comment: There are terms specific to fields -even humorous.  Is there an arena of 'expertise' associated?

Comment: Not in this instance, no.

Comment: There goes my dream of using 'hamartiologist';-)

Comment: I just recently learned the word 'hamartia', Third News.  :)  #TheFaultInOurStars

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider "**[expertise](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/expertise)**."

> expertise: expert advise or opinion; skill or knowledge in a particular area

"*But in the absence of such an actual expert, I have learned that the above is a losing battle.  I am being dragged, kicking and screaming, into [**widget expertise**](http://www.sidehustlenation.com/is-it-fair-that-online-retailers-dont-charge-sales-tax/)*."

Alternately, "**[expertism](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/expertism)**" might also work for what you're looking for.

Comment: Yes I did consider that... but expertise is a thing unto itself, not the state of being an expert.  Regardless, I will accept your answer if nothing else comes along that supports my intentionally-quirky sentence.

Answer (score 2):

For the exact case you specify, being a "widget guru" or guru-dom is used a lot.

Answer (score 2):

Try

> I am being dragged, kicking and screaming, into *widgetary omniscience*.

(I have a cat called Widget, so I consider myself something of an expert on those grounds alone.  :-)

Answer (score 1):

I think maybe you want an **authority**.  Because their opinion is **authoritative**.

> able to be trusted as being accurate or true; reliable.

If it is meant to be funny/sarcastic then I would go with **master/kingdom**.

You can also consider **bravura** which is a bit of a funny word and would probably only be used in jest for everyday dialogue.

> great skill, enthusiasm, and confidence

Comment: I was going for quirky humor, but I failed to explain that.  I'll fix my question.

Comment: @RyanV.Bissell - added a sarcastic bit.

Answer (score 1):

A person who is an expert is **accomplished** in their field of expertise.  Less used is the term **au fait** or [fully informed; in touch or expert](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/au+fait)